# Solr index - what is included

Tags: solr

I try to analyse why my Solr index is so big.

I have a Solr index with ~15000 documents.
Each document has 50 fields.
The avg doc size is ~40kB.

Solr admin UI shows that the segment file has 4.6GB, but the index size is 12.11GB

I can't find any documentation, what exactly is included in the index so that I can figure out why the index is that large.

Comment: Everything that you're storing, tokens that you're generating, etc. If you haven't optimized your index after reindexing (and haven't hit the merge factor), every deleted document, etc. is still present (which means that reindexing will double your index size). Run `optimize` to rewrite the index to a single file again. Since 40kb * 15000 is 600MB just by raw content (in bytes - if you mean 40k characters, more space will be used because of UTF). So if we assume that every field is both indexed and stored, depending on uniqueness of tokens, you're going to get close to 1.2GB without overhead.

Comment: I executed optimize. Only 1 segment file exists.

Comment: Then that's the size with all tokens and stored content and metadata overhead. Seeing as you're indexing at least 600MB of raw content, 4.6GB actually stored doesn't seem too far off when you consider what tokens gets generated and what you're storing in your index. Exactly how quickly the index grows depends on their fields and their definitions (i.e. a ngram filter or a large synonym expansion will generate far more tokens than just a `string` or keywordtokenizer field)

Comment: Any copyfield instructions will also make the index larger, such as the default copyField to `_text_` which will double your index size (depending on the tokens themselves). Smaller tokens will also be larger when stored, since any reference will attach a lucene document id as well, which can be larger than the term itself (so more than double in size - `a` is a single character, but the document id will be at least four bytes (not sure about the actual size these days, if it's still an int or a long now).